# Can I debug a program in Verifone Verix OS?

Tags: verifone

Is it possible to debug a program created for Verix OX directly on a Verifone terminal? If this is not possible, is there an emulator for Verix OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with RVD but pretty hard and hardly convenient. The description is in the SDK documentation (programming tools reference manual).

Comment: Agreed. I've spent more time trying to get the darn debugger working than it would have taken to just add LogPrintf statements or even just printing things to the receipt tape or screen.  My advice is not to mess with the debugger.  It looks like such a great idea, but even if you get it working, it messing with timings and everything else.